# Kara at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 千円、ここに置いておくからね。

For this sentence may I know what kara at the end of sentence means? As I understand, the whole sentence means "I will leave 1,000 yen here for you"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I hear ますから (masukara) so often at the end of sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58773/why-do-i-hear-%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-masukara-so-often-at-the-end-of-sentences)

Comment: Also related: [Clarifying だから use at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4033/5010)

Comment: 「から」represents  理由・原因・動機・根拠
so I ,Japanese, understand the meaning as 
"I will leave 1,000 yen here , please accept it".
And we don't indicate an objective person in Japanese sentence ( It shall be led by context) .
Japanese often omit the sentence that is clear to understand from the context.