# What is the difference between だから　and なので

Tags: meaning

I'm talking about using them at the start of the sentence, meaning "so" or "therefore".

「今日は暇だ」
「だから、映画でも見に行こう?」/「なので、映画でも見に行こう?」

I'm assuming that the difference is simply the same as the difference when they are used as a conjunction in the middle. That is to say, なので is slightly more objective and polite.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7

Comment: I'll show you a good artcle about your question here (http://www.tv-asahi.co.jp/announcer/nihongo/labo/lab_012/body.html)